# When i measure the running time of an algorithm that should be of O(n) = n, i am getting O(n) = 1. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I am self studying data structures and i am trying to measure differences in time complexities between efficient and inefficient ways of implementing the append method to an array data structure. That said, according to some math i did on paper, the inefficient way should be O(n) = n^2 and the efficient way should be O(n) = n.

The problem is that, when I run the simulations and plot both situations on a graph, the inefficient way performs as expected, but the efficient way performs O(n) = 1. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import datetime
import time
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Inefficient append
class PyListInef:
   
   
   def __init__(self):
       self.items = []
   
   def append(self, item):
       # Inefficient append -> appending n items to the list causes a O(n) = n^2, since for each i for i in 1, 2, 3...n 
       # we need i * k operations in order to append every element to the new list. Then, by weak induction we prove 
       # that the number of required operations is n(n+1)/2 which implies O(n) = n^2
       self.items = self.items + [item]
       
   # Using magic method for our PyList to be an iterable object.
   def __iter__(self):
       for c in self.items:
           yield c
           
# Efficient append:

class PyList:
   def __init__(self):
       self.items = []
   
   def append(self, item):
       self.items.append(item)
   
   def __iter__(self):
       for c in self.items:
           yield c

# The inefficient append running time

lst = PyListInef()

time_dict_inef = dict()
time_dict_ef = dict()

series = np.linspace(1, 301, 300)

   
time.sleep(2)
   
for i in range(300):
   starttime = time.time()
   for j in range(i):
       lst.append(series[j])
       
   elapsed_time = time.time() - starttime
   time_dict_inef[i] = elapsed_time * 100000
   
# The efficient append running time

lst = PyList()

time.sleep(2)

for i in range(300):
   starttime = time.time()
   for j in range(i):
       lst.append(series[j])
       
   elapsed_time = time.time() - starttime
   time_dict_ef[i] = elapsed_time * 100000

plt.figure(figsize = (14,7))
plt.plot(time_dict_inef.keys(), time_dict_inef.values())
plt.plot(time_dict_ef.keys(), time_dict_ef.values())
plt.xlabel('Number of elements to append')
plt.ylabel('Elapsed time (microseconds)')
plt.title('Comparison between efficient appending vs inefficient appending in a list data structure')
plt.show()
```

[image: Text]

Could you please help me and point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of timing a single run, try timing 100/1000 runs?

Comment: Use much higher n like 1,10,100,1000,10000,10000  Timings that are few microseconds are mostly useless because of system overheads, setup-times ...

Comment: I''ll try to do that!! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time.time()` has a limited resolution. Your "efficient append" timings are fast enough that they usually finish before a single tick of `time.time()`'s resolution. Note how exactly two times show up in your yellow graph: 0 ticks, and 1 tick. The 1-tick times are more frequent on the right of the graph, because even when the times are shorter than a single tick, a longer time means a higher probability that the tick will happen during the runtime. If you ran with larger inputs, you would eventually see 2-tick times and higher. (Also note that 100000 doesn't have enough 0s in it, so your timings are off by a factor of 10.)

Comment: Thank you very much, user2357112 supports Monica! I just noticed the missing 0 haha. It's 2 A.M in my timezone and i am a bit tired.. I think that it is time to go to bed. 

Do you know if there is any workaround for the limitations of time.time() in order to measure the efficient function and get something that resembles a straight line?